# Excel-VBA Listrow.add not inserting row

Tags: vba, excel

I have a bit of code that checks a userform for data in a combobox. Then if found adds a row to the table. Unfortunately, I am finding that some times it does not add the row and just overwrites the line. Any ideas on what I have done wrong would help. The following is the code for the portion that creates the new line:

```
If Not vbNullString = Me.CrimeSN2.Value Then
    If Not vbNullString = Me.RowNumber.Value Then
        rownumval = Me.RowNumber.Value
        Worksheets("Offense").ListObjects("OffenseTable").ListRows.Add (rownumval)
        rownumval = rownumval + 1
    Else
        rownumval = LastRow + 1
        Worksheets("Offense").ListObjects("OffenseTable").ListRows.Add (rownumval)
        rownumval = rownumval + 1
end if
```

Comment: Does it just overwrite the last row of your table? Does it happen during the `If` or the `Else` part of your code, or both? Is LastRow correct when you step through your code using F8?

Comment: You check if the cell value (`Me.RowNumber.Value`) is not Null, however, it may not be a number. If it's not a number, the .Add will fail.

Comment: Thanks for the response Doug and OldUgly, to respond to your inquiry. It overwrites at the location of the rownumval+1. I stepped through the code and it only overwrites on the `If` portion. and LastRow is correct. I have stepped through it and it reads rownumval as a long and has value. it just seems to not work on the `.ListRows.Add (rownumval)`. To Old Ugly  `Me.RowNumber.Value` is reading as long and has value. I did try the code you provided but still continues with the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will provide further protection against having a non-number in `rownumval`

```
If Not vbNullString = Me.CrimeSN2.Value Then
    If Not vbNullString = Me.RowNumber.Value And IsNumeric(Me.RowNumber.Value) Then
        rownumval = Me.RowNumber.Value
        Worksheets("Offense").ListObjects("OffenseTable").ListRows.Add (rownumval)
        rownumval = rownumval + 1
    Else
        rownumval = LastRow + 1
        Worksheets("Offense").ListObjects("OffenseTable").ListRows.Add (rownumval)
        rownumval = rownumval + 1
end if
```